# Clipping Tops of Waveforms in Python

Tags: python, audio

I'm generating tones in Python to be written to a WAV file:

```
def generateTone(note):
    # generates a sine wave in a note's frequency
    tone = []
    framerate = 44100
    noteLookup = {'d':293.665,'a':440,'g':391.995}
    frequency = noteLookup[note]
    for i in range(framerate):
        tone.append(math.sin(2.0*math.pi*float(frequency)*(float(i)/float(framerate))))
    return tone
```

However, as you may expect, these pure sine waves sound less than pleasing to the ear. From what I [understand](http://www.geofex.com/effxfaq/distn101.htm), 'clipping' the tops off of these sine waves, preferably in such a way as to leave smooth corners instead of a sudden cutoff, will improve the sound of these tones significantly. This is the idea:

[image: clipped waves]
<sub>(source: [geofex.com](http://www.geofex.com/effxfaq/d101_02.gif))</sub>

With that said, I have no idea how to approach doing so.

How would one going about setting (preferably in an easy-to-adjust way) a threshold at which the sine waves generated above will be smoothly clipped in such a manner as shown in the figure?

Comment: clipping? Your data is still represented by `float` precision. How many bytes will you use to represent the sample? 1, 2, 4 bytes? You have to decide it first then we can answer your question. BTW, `sine` wave is not pleasing to the ear because it doesn't have harmonic.

Comment: The wave generated here is later scaled to 16 bit, then written out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have a mapping that introduces "soft clipping" - the values are 1:1 linear until they get near the threshold, then get compressed up until they meet some larger threshold.

Edit: The idea was sound, but the implementation left a little to be desired. I gave it some more thought and replaced it with something better.

The goal is to make a smooth transition from the start of compression to the hard clipping limit. A linear transform has a slope of 1, and a clipped signal has a slope of 0. The cleanest way to transition from a slope of 1 to a slope of 0 is to use a quarter of a sine wave, so the updated function is based on `sin`.

```
from math import *

hard_limit = 32767
linear_limit = 23197  # -3 dB
clip_limit = linear_limit + int(pi/2 * (hard_limit - linear_limit))

def soft_clip(n):
    amplitude, sign = abs(n), 1 if n >= 0 else -1
    if amplitude <= linear_limit:
        return n
    if amplitude >= clip_limit:
        return hard_limit * sign
    scale = hard_limit - linear_limit
    compression = scale * sin(float(amplitude - linear_limit) / scale)
    return (linear_limit + int(compression)) * sign
```

Here's an example of the above used on a sine wave of amplitude 40000, with the unclipped version in the background.

[image: Soft clipping demo]